# Condição JS imprimindo <div> HTML

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Estou querendo criar uma condição em JS que recebo um objeto em um arquivo `.html` da seguinte forma:

```
<a each="gabarito in $this.gabaritosCopy">    
    <script> if (gabarito.valor == 'N') { </script>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <span class="col-md-4">Copiar</span>
        </div>
    <script> } </script>
    ...
</a>
```

Só que não funciona, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo de condição que seja plausível com o seu problema? Quais são as variáveis e em que condições precisará exibir o HTML?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss melhorei o exemplo na pergunta !

Comment: Está usando algum framework que te permite fazer `gabarito in $this.gabaritosCopy`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Angular !

Comment: Então basta utilizar a diretiva [`NgIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: NgIf a partir do angular 2 não se implementa @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Pelo que consta, essa é a documentação da versão 7.2.15